# How does resonance lead to an increase in the overall voltage?

Tags: voltage, resonance

How exactly does resonance lead to an increase in the overall voltage greater than that of the supplied voltage?

Comment: What did you read and what did you not understand? Please [Edit] and include details in your question.

Comment: The most accurate answer is probably "pretty fast"

Comment: Resonance means energy is being stored. When you keep storing something, it goes up. Like how if you push a swing properly it keeps getting higher and higher despite your first push not having enough energy to send it that high.

Comment: There are some resonant circuits where the voltage risee does not occur. Please be more specific.

Comment: By drawing more current: a resonant circuit which has apparent [voltage or current] gain, is actually a transformer (input and output impedances are in a ratio).

Comment: Think about pushing your friend or sibling on a child's swing. If you 'time' small pushes just right the amplitude of the swing oscillation will increase for each cycle until something limits it. The reason is that the energy from previous pushes is still, in part, present in the swing system.

Comment: Why are you using the term "overall voltage"? In a series resonance the 'overall voltage' is the applied voltage. Once you accept the fact that the current is the same in both elements, the fact that one element can reach a voltage higher than the applied voltage is a direct consequence of the phase difference between V and I in each dynamic element. Fix your attention on the current sinusoid and then look at the voltages sinusoids for L and C: one is shifted to left, the other to the right. If the sum has to be Vapplied, when one instantaneous value is lower then that of the applied V...

Answer (score 4):

Your question made me go back 15 years when I was able to intuitively explain the operation of the LC tank and told it in a [Wikibooks story](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/How_do_We_Create_Sinusoidal_Oscillations%3F). Maybe it's time to finish it by  answering your question? Let me try...

The LC tank consists of two energy containers connected to each other. They are heterogeneous - one (capacitor) can accumulate "potential energy" and the other (coil) "kinetic energy". When we put initial energy into this system, it begins to move (oscillate) endlessly between them. The reason for this is that the capacitor reverses the direction of current flow when fully charged and the coil maintains (through its "inertia") the direction of current when the voltage crosses the zero point.

So while individually the capacitor and inductor are "static containers", the LC tank is a "dynamic container" of continuously transforming energy. In the ideal case, there is no loss and the energy will be stored forever... and if we add new (even small) portions of energy, it (and the voltage amplitude of oscillations) will continuously grow. The question is how and when to add these small portions because the energy (voltage) is constantly moving (oscillating). Or, in the popular life analogy, when should we push the swing to keep it swinging continuously?

Actually, we need to periodically add a small voltage to the capacitor voltage. In my opinion, ***it is most convenient to do it when the voltage across the capacitor is zero by briefly connecting a voltage source in parallel to the capacitor.*** Thus we will observe how, with each subsequent cycle, a small-amplitude impulse input voltage causes a continuous increase in the amplitude of the output voltage across the LC tank. This is actually how electronic oscillators work.

Here is an attempt at such an experiment. I would not say it is exactly what I expected...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuSoFM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: LC tank resonance transistor pulse input]

In the life analogy, this means pushing the swing just as it passes through the vertical (zero) position. This will allow us to stay in one place and not move as the swing amplitude increases. We usually maintain a constant swing amplitude; so we prefer to push the swing when it has stopped at the highest position.

If we directly connect the input sinusoidal source to the LC tank (perhaps through a resistor), we will observe that the amplitude of the LC voltage continuously rises and stops when it equals the input voltage. This is the classic arrangement for observing the resonance phenomenon in electric circuits where the LC voltage does not exceed the input voltage.

Here is a (more successful) example arrangement:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBgEeA.png)</sup>

**In time domain:**

[image: LC tank resonance time domain]

**In frequency domain:**

[image: LC tank resonance frequency domain]

However, it turned out the resonance phenomenon is best manifested when the input source is connected in series:

**Sine AC input voltage:**

[image: schematic]

[image: LC tank resonance series input]

Obviously, in the parallel arrangement, the LC tank is shunted.

**Square AC input voltage:**

[image: LC tank resonance series square input]

It is clearly seen how the output voltage "jumps" with the input step value.