How does voltage increase due to oscillation in resonant circuit?
I am new to resonant circuits or LLC circuit concept. What I understand from information acquired from the internet resources and ChatGPT, at resonant frequency, capacitive and inductive reactance are same and nullify each other. In this condition, the voltage in the circuit increases and the circuit delivers maximum power. Trying to go deep in the topic, I am curious about how exactly does energy oscillations between capacitor and inductor cause the voltage to magnify.
My hunch is:
As the voltage and current are shifted by (or the current lags the voltage by) 90 degrees, when the voltage has charged the capacitor, the current is still at the inductor and has stored the energy in the form of magnetic field. Now the back emf generated by dissipating the energy from the inductor, this back emf adds to the voltage at the capacitor terminals.
I apologize if it is far from reality — I went through consdierable website articles but couldn't find a clear explanation hence I went to dig deep about it and this is the opinion i could form. However I am sceptical about this theory so I have come to this forum for help.

Please remove anything stated by ChatGPT. You can ask a question without saying what ChatGPT told you. It is irrelevant.

@Justme Sorry sir, I am just telling about the research I did before coming to this forum with question.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/662089/how-does-resonance-lead-to-an-increase-in-the-overall-voltage

Using chatGPT is invalid research effort for this site and is like a red-rag to a bull. You haven't shown a circuit either.

@Andyaka I went through considerable articles and websites before going to the chatbot for a straight answer. It might sound naive but honestly on many cases chatbots do provide helpful answers with source of information as footnotes. Some people I asked this doubt, find it safe to "assume" some things and move forward. And I think this is just about a general L-C resonant circuit. Do I need to put a circuit? If you think so I will do.

@PankitShah - Hi, To expand on what Andy aka commented above, we do not allow questions which ask about genAI responses - see this Meta discussion. We don't care whether ChatGPT agreed with something or not. Posting a question here is asking people to help you, and voting on that Meta discussion has clearly shown that people here do not want to spend their valuable time pointing out issues in genAI responses. So, please, explain your question, link to websites from your research etc. but do not quote or refer to genAI responses. TY

@SamGibson Sir, I apologise if my post is being misinterpreted. This post is NOT about the ChatGPT response. I am just discussing here about the basic concept behind voltage increase in resonant circuit and about the resources I went through one of which  was ChatGPT. I went to other articles first and had formed an opinion about which i went to a chatbot. So the subject here is voltage magnification in resonant circuit and not ChatGPT. However if it still comes around as the kind of question you are talking about, i will remove that part. Thank you.

Present day LLMs are trained to give plausible sounding answers, rhetoric, think politicians trying to persuade you. Future LLMs may be trained to give correct answers, we'll have to wait and see. Until then, avoid them for any technical help.

Think a circuit which has in series a 10 ohm resistor, a capacitor which has capacitive reactance 100 ohms at 60 Hz and an inductor which has inductive reactance 100 ohms at 60 Hz. That circuit is connected to 60 Hz sinusoidal AC voltage source which outputs 10 volts RMS voltage. The voltages over the inductor and the capacitor are lifted to 100 volts by the series LC resonance:

The voltage- and current meters are assumed to be ideal, so they do not at all affect the circuit.
The same 60 Hz AC current flows through the resistor, capacitor and the inductor. That implies the capacitor and the inductor both have sinusoidal voltages over them. If the current in the circuit is Ix, the voltage over the capacitor and over the inductor are both Ix*100 ohm. But they have opposite phases, so the voltages over the inductor and the capacitor cancel each other exactly. This is series LC resonance.  All of the source voltage 10 volts is over the resistor.
The opposite phases come from the fact that the phase angles of the voltages are shifted 90 degrees from the phase angle of the current, but to opposite directions. Total phase difference between the voltages is 180 degrees.
As said the 10 V source voltage is over the 10 ohm resistor, so the AC current in the circuit must be 1 ampere RMS.
1A current through the capacitor makes 100V voltage over it and 1A current through the inductor makes 100V voltage over it, so this circuit lifts the voltage from 10V to 100V.
You can try to simulate this. You will not get exactly 100 volts over the capacitor and over the inductor, because in practical simulators the parts have some inbuilt resistance to avoid division by zero in case of resonances and you can only input rounded component values like L=265mH and C=26.5uF, you cannot input exact reactances 100 ohms capacitive and 100 ohms inductive. The result is that the lifted voltage will be few volts below 100 volts.
Do not expect the high voltage stays as high if you connect a load for example over the inductor. It's not any more the same circuit.
The next circuit works with DC. LC resonance doubles the voltage. Or actually only nearly doubles it, because the voltage drop in the diode is quite high due high peak current:

The simulator gives these capacitor voltage and charging current:

The simulator assumes that the capacitor is empty at t=0. The charging current starts to grow gradually. When the capacitor voltage reaches the input DC voltage the inductor current starts to decrease, but the charging still goes on. Finally the charging current is zero. The diode prevents discharging, so the capacitor voltage stays in its peak value. This makes possible to see the phenomenon in a built circuit if one has a typical 10 megaohm digital multimeter. No oscilloscope is needed. The voltage decays slowly due the discharging current caused by the multimeter, but it stays long enough to be red.

@Tim Williams Someone upvoted and the image inserting edit button became available. I inserted my original image and  texts which support it. Your simulation used different numbers and the approximated L and C values and inbuilt non-idealities of  simulator's part library gave other high output voltage than exact 100Vrms.

Hm, interesting. The simulator for its part, is pretty accurate, it does what it says on the tin; CircuitLab does not use parasitic resistance, and AFAIK, a variant of trapezoidal integration. Looks like reducing timestep to 1us is necessary to get the gain close here, so it's numerical loss. The AC analysis shows correct (and ~instantaneous) results of course (20dB gain at peak).

A resonant circuit is something like an LC "tank" circuit where energy sloshes back and forth between the capacitor and the inductor. Ideally, if there were no resistive or other losses that would continue forever. A measure of how close we get to that is the circuit 'Q'. A high Q circuit has very little loss and will continue to 'ring' at the resonant frequency for many cycles.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

This is something like pushing a child on a swing. The energy is potential energy when she is at the top of the swing's motion and the energy is kinetic as she whooshes past at the bottom of the swing's motion. If you give the swing a small push every cycle the motion will increase and increase until it becomes too scary or something else happens (like the swing going slack at the top).
Similarly, if you pump a bit of energy in the tank circuit each cycle, more than the losses, the energy will build up until something happens- maybe it arcs, maybe the losses in the inductor core increase with the current swings until they match the energy you are putting in, etc. The resonant circuit stores energy so you can keep adding to it on every cycle. It does not end up with more energy than you put into it, of course, but the current and voltage can be higher than if the resonant circuit was not there, provided you're not draining too much energy per cycle from the resonant circuit.

Perhaps this sim of an ideal LC oscillating circuit will help (below):
It starts with 10V on the capacitor.  As expected, the voltage (green trace) reaches maximum when the capacitor and inductor currents are zero (red and purple traces) and zero volts when the currents are maximum.
The energy reaches a peak in one element while it is zero in the other.  The blue trace is inductor stored energy (1/2 LI²) and the yellow trace is capacitor stored energy (1/2 CV²). (The vertical scales are in milli-joules).
Thus the inductor energy peak is when the current is maximum, and the capacitor energy peak is when the voltage is maximum.
So basically the energy in the tank circuit bounces back and forth between the capacitor and the inductor in a sinusoidal fashion.  Adding any energy to the tank will, of course, increase its peak voltage and current swing.
Does that help with your understanding?


The resonance of an LC circuit is in my mind best approached through a hydraulic analogy. Consider the water in this u-tube, illustration from here

The capacitor stores energy through its electrical potential. It's at a maximum when the voltage is maximum and no current flows. The water in the u-tube stores potential energy though the difference in gravitational potential, the level, between the two arms. It's a maximum when the height difference is maximum, and no water flows.
The inductor stores energy in the magnetic field in the core, generated by the current flowing through it. It's maximum when the current is maximum, and there's no voltage across it. The column of water stores kinetic energy through its speed. It's maximum when it flows fastest, which is when the two columns of water are level.
Energy shuttles back and forth between the two storage mechanisms. If there is no dissipation, the maximum voltage, current, speed, level difference stay the same. In real passive circuits, there's some dissipation, and the oscillation dies away. In a driven circuit, the oscillation level can build up and up, until the dissipation through losses equals the energy input from the drive. With low losses, this can means oscillations build to a very high level.

An LC tank consists of two energy containers connected to each other. They are heterogeneous - one (capacitor) can accumulate "potential energy" and the other (coil) "kinetic energy". When we put initial energy into this system, it begins to move (oscillate) endlessly between them. The reason for this is that the capacitor reverses the direction of current flow when fully charged and the coil maintains (through its "inertia") the direction of current when the voltage crosses the zero point.
So while individually the capacitor and inductor are "static containers", the LC tank is a "dynamic container" of continuously transforming energy. In the ideal case, there is no loss and the energy will be stored forever... and if we add new (even small) portions of energy, it (and the voltage amplitude of oscillations) will continuously grow. The question is how and when to add these small portions because the energy (voltage) is constantly moving (oscillating). Or, in the popular life analogy, when should we push the swing to keep it swinging continuously?
We can easily guess that we have to periodically add a small portion of voltage to the capacitor voltage with the natural LC frequency. Thus we will observe how, with each subsequent cycle, it causes a continuous increase in the amplitude of the output voltage across the LC tank.
In the arrangement below, the resonance phenomenon is demonstrated by an AC input voltage source with small amplitude that is connected in series to  the LC tank.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

